# Is it good to subclass NSInvocationOperation to add an iVar to track the kind of Operation?

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue, nsinvocationoperation

I wanted to identify each of the NSInvocationOperation to identify what this operation in the isFinished in the KVO notification.

So I am planning to not to maintain the NSInvocationOperation as an iVAr in my VC. But when I get KVO notification, I wanted to be able to identify the NSInvocationOperation. So I am planning to add a tag (by subclassing the NSInvocationOperation) which can store values with which  I can use to identify the operation.

Is this a good way to identify the object? Is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [Associative References](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) in a category. It would remove the need to rewrite existing code to use your subclass.

I've been using it in a similar case, works just fine!